# I used Segoe Script for a logo comission but it’s license is only for free for Personal Use

Tags: logo, copyright, font-licensing

I made a logo commission a few months ago
And while I designed the images myself I used the Segoe Script font for the words.

I’ve only recently read that it’s only legal for PERSONAL USE. What should I do? Is there any way to pay for the royalty so I can use it legally or should I redesign the logo using a legal font and send it to the client?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This isn't legal advice. I'm not a legal professional. If you want legal advice, hire a lawyer.

This is a quote from the [Microsoft Font Licensing FAQs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/font-faq) about the fonts that come pre-installed as part of Windows Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, and 10, which include Segoe Script.

> **Can I sell things I print from Windows or make using these printouts,
> say a book, logo, advertisement, report, t-shirt, or crafts that use
> fonts that come with Windows?**
>
> Unless you are using an application that is specifically licensed for
> home, student, or non-commercial use, we do not restrict you from
> selling the things you print and make using the Windows-supplied
> fonts.
>
> **Can I make a company logo using the fonts?**
>
> Unless you are using an application that is specifically licensed for
> home, student, or non-commercial use, we do not restrict you from
> making logos using the Windows-supplied fonts.

If you don't have an operating system which already includes the font, you can buy it here: https://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/segoe-script/licenses

If you already have a version of Windows which includes this font then you already have a Desktop EULA Licence. You can view the complete licence here: https://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/segoe-script/licenses#

Comment: Damn I never knew about it. So you can't use Windows 10 Home fonts for commercial use? But can you use fonts in Windows 10 Pro?

Comment: @Vikas No, that would be ridiculous. It says "applications which are specifically licensed for home use". The operating system isn't an application. - I assume they mean MS Office which they sell as home and student versions.

Comment: @Vikas - nobody with any sense would use Office to design logos anyway, so it's all a bit silly!

Answer (score 0):

I'm **not** a lawyer, never have been. And this is **not** legal advice in any interpretation. You need to speak to an attorney to understand any legal ramifications this situation may present.

---

You need to contact the vendor to see if you can purchase a commercial license. 
It's doubtful anyone here will know for certain.

If this were to somehow happen to me, I would *rapidly* move forward with a rework of the logo using a font that **is** licensed for commercial use. This would be my *top priority* and all other work would take a back seat. This needs to be complete absolutely as quickly as possible.

When the rework is complete, I would *then* contact the client explaining the problem, and then offering the solution immediately. So the client isn't waiting in anticipation hoping to avoid any legal problems.

Be aware, if the client has to spend money to recreate things with the existing logo on them - such and stationary, signage, etc. - they *may* want compensation for any such expenditures. Since, clearly, this issue has only arisen because of the lack of due diligence on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Segoe + its variants are Microsoft's. They have enough power to bring home every penny+a hefty interest% in every possible case where something is available.

Do not believe some grey font download sites. Ask Microsoft or check their font licensing to see what they actually want and start to find an alternative, if you cannot see you can legally use the font as you want.

I am not a lawyer, so this cannot be a legal advice. Consider the next as my unqualified finding:

Segoe Script is a part of Windows. If you have a legal version of Windows which allows commercial works and you use applications which allow commercial work, then there's no problem to produce business logos as long as you are not trying to distribute the font. Give to the customer only a vector version of the logo which doesn't contain the font file; for that convert text parts to outlines.

To confirm read this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/segoe-script

BTW: You may see that most of us do not dare to give legal advice. That's because the adviser may be forced to pay the damage that obeying his advice causes in a court of law.

Answer (score 0):

Just use google to find a vendor that sells the font. The good thing is that almost no font designer would make a font available for free personal use when they do not also sell them. It is like providing a demo version you could say.

https://www.fontshop.com/families/segoe-script/buy

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ascender/segoe-script/

Then make sure the font you purchased is absolutely the same as the one you used and the characters you used are identical in both fonts.

The chance that they would catch & sue you when you illegally use a popular font for a small company is very low. But anyhow my font teacher once told us that he bought his private plane from what he earned from a lawsuit against someone that used his font in a newspaper advert. So it is really not worth the risk. And of course also immoral and disrespectful towards the font designer.